# Mark cell as a selected while returning to the controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uicollectionview

Is it a way to mark a cell as a sellected while you back to the "filtering" view. The table view or a collection view should know if the cell is selected, if yes then it should invoke `didDeselectItemAt` instead of `didSelectItemAt`.

Bacically I've tryed with cell.isSelected = true but it is going to freeze the views, or `tableView/collectionView.selectItem` does not work well.

For now what I've figure out is

```
if !choosenData.isEmpty && choosenData.contains(tmpData[image]!) {
                    imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
                    imageView = UIImageView.init().drawRingForCircle(imageView: image, color: .white)
                }
```

Inside the `cellForItemAt`.

Is there any thing which would tell the tableView/collectionView to invoke `didDeselectItemAt` after this condition is true ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: just store the indexpath of the selected cell & call setSelected method of tableview in ViewwillAppear.   or look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295297/uitableviewcell-set-selected-initially

Comment: Thank you! I have not find this answer.

Comment: did you get answer of your question? if 'Yes' then enjoy :)

Comment: I am kinda struggling with condition atm. How it could be.