# Issue deselecting tableView cell | Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

When selecting and deselecting a record found in a tableView cell I have a checkmark accessory appear.

**I am doing so as the following:**

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectRow()
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }
```

**The issue is it always takes two taps to deselect the checkmark if the record already exists when the tableView is first loaded.**

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        unselectRow()
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
    }
```

**The tableView is based on JSON with the following structure:**

```
var structure = [JSONStructure]()

struct JSONStructure: Codable {
    var peron: String
    var update: Int
}
```

If `update` is has a value of 100 a checkmark is applied if the value is a 200 no checkmark is applied.

**This is done in `cellForRowAt` as the following:**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let TableInfo: JSONStructure

if (TableInfo.update == 100) {
cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
} else {
cell.accessoryType = .none
  }
}
```

When the tableView first loads and a checkmark already exist because the `update` criteria is met, how can I prevent having to double press to unselect the record?

Answer (score 0):

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) 
            cell.accessoryType = .none

    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
         let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) 
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark


    }
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellData", forIndexPath: indexPath) 
    if (TableInfo.update == 100)
        cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Bottom)
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = .None
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain your code? Why are doing scroll position?

Answer (score 0):

Your `cellForRowAt` only marks the Cell visually (setting accessoryType), but you need to mark it as checked for the UITableView logic too. Implement `willDisplay` on your delegate and update the selected state there. Example:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  // .. get TableInfo for indexPath.row
  let TableInfo: JSONStructure

  if (TableInfo.update == 100) {
    tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableView.ScrollPosition.none)
  } else {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
  }
}
```

See f.e. [UITableViewCell Set selected initially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295297/uitableviewcell-set-selected-initially/19296095) although some of the options differ in wether `cellForRowAt` or `willDisplayCell` is used.

See [iOS UITableView: what's the different between "cellForRowAtIndexPath" and "willDisplayCell: forRowAtIndexPath:"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31988450/ios-uitableview-whats-the-different-between-cellforrowatindexpath-and-willd) on why to use `willDisplay` vs. `cellForRowAt` for the selection.

Comment: I appreciate your help, I think you may have a typo, I get the error `Extra argument 'scrollPosition' in call`

Comment: Fixed, copy and paste is bad and so on.

Comment: Now I get the error Constant 'TableInfo' used before being initialized. This doesn't make sense to me since it is defined right above the conditional

Comment: Yes, it is uninitialized. Thats from the code you wrote in your Question. You probably need to set `let TableInfo: JSONStructure = structure[indexPath.row]` if `structure` is your data for the table.