# what is the different between isSelected method of tableviewcell and selectRow(at:animated:scrollPosition:) of tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

what is the different between `isSelected` method of tableviewcell and `selectRow(at:animated:scrollPosition:)` of tableview when i want to set a cell to be selected?

i.e.
`cell.isSelected = true` vs `tableview.selectRow(at:index, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)`

I found most people use the latter，but i do not known why

Comment: Which should you use? Depends entirely on your goal... Single select table view? Multi-select? Perform an Action on selection? No way to tell you without a complete explanation of what you want to do. What's the difference? Read the docs... write some code... see which works for your task.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295297/uitableviewcell-set-selected-initially, in this post, it has said : ```selectRow(at:animated:scrollPosition:) ```allow the user to deselect the cell. If this is missing it cannot be unselected

Comment: because of the cell reuse so cannot be unselected？

Comment: You still haven't told us ***why*** you want to manually change the selection.... it's *very* difficult to answer your question without context or a detailed description of what you're trying to accomplish. Either edit your question with details, or, better, experiment with the different methods yourself to get a full understanding.

Answer (score 0):

one Work on the cell : means that you have pointer to it (mainly it is done in didSelectRow to unselect the row after pushing a detail view for example). The other tell the table view to select the cell not having to have a reference to it.

Comment: So which method should I use when I want to set a cell to be selected?

Comment: When creatong the cell  cell.isSelected. If other place in view controller managing the tableview selectRow

Comment: see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295297/uitableviewcell-set-selected-initially  post, it has said : ```selectRow(at:animated:scrollPosition:)``` allow the user to deselect the cell. If this is missing it cannot be unselected

Comment: because of the cell reuse so cannot be unselected？

Answer (score 0):

**selectRow(at:animated:scrollPosition:)**

Selects a row in the table view identified by index path, optionally scrolling the row to a location in the table view.

**cell.isSelected**

`isSelected` bool affects the appearance of the cell. the default value is false.

For more info:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623263-isselected
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614875-selectrow

Comment: So which method should I use when I want to set a cell to be selected? And why

Comment: @Joiner It depends on your requirement, if you have the cell object in the place where you want to set a cell to be selected, go with isSelected else go with selectRow(at:animated:scrollPosition:)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295297/uitableviewcell-set-selected-initially, in this post, it has said : ```selectRow(at:animated:scrollPosition:) ``` allow the user to deselect the cell. If this is missing it cannot be unselected, so it seems recommended use ```selectRow(at:animated:scrollPosition:) ```

Comment: because of the cell reuse so cannot be unselected？